# Why does my rendered movie clip have no audio?

Tags: tracking, audio, movie-clip-editor

I am a Blender newbie, and know that I will have to supply additional info...Please be patient with me :-)

I followed this video by Oliver Villar, https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=nU8zqn091rM. I am using a 54 second video shot with a phone. The rendered AVI video has no audio.

I used a single tracker, placed on the cross on the green parament, to do the 2D stabilization.
The original video is here: https://vimeo.com/229907878 
The stabilized video is here: https://vimeo.com/229907728 
Here is a screenshot of how my compositor is set up:

[image: Compositor Setup]

Let me know of anything else I can provide. And, thanks so much for the help!

Answer (score 1):

Have you selected a audio codec before rendering ? 
By default it's on "none"
(Properties panel -> render -> encoding)
[image]

Comment: I have tried both MP3 and AAC

Comment: So you can manually add the audio of your video in the Video Sequence Editor. Add your scene (Add -> scene) and then add the sound by choosing your video clip (Add -> sound). It work for me.

Answer (score 0):

Very late to the party, but I just had this problem and solved it:

At least in Blender 2.9+ it could be because you have to tick both "Compositor" and "Sequencer" in the Output Properties tab. This is because the Audio is loaded in the sequencer but the actual stabilisation happens in the Compositor via Nodes.

[image: Output Properties tab]